# TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

i've been coding this:

```
    function deleteSheets(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();


  for(var i = 0; i<=sheets.length; i++){

    var name = sheets[i].getName();

    if (name == "aux"){
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }else if(name == "nulos"){

      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);

      }



    /* switch(sheets[i].getName()){

      case sheets[i].getName() == "aux":
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
        break;

      case sheets[i].getName() == "nulos":
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
        break;

      case name == "aux":
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
        break; 
  }

  */

}

}
```

Tried to do a simple "deleteSheet" with switch, which didn't work, then with a if just to see the same error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined. (line 8, file "Code")

What am I missing? Pretty sure i've already done a similar thing before...
(If it's obvious, i'm sorry, i'm noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake on your for statement.

You wrote:

```
for(var i = 0; i<=sheets.length; i++){}
```

but when i = sheets.length, you're out of your array, so you try to call getName() of nothing. You should have

```
for(var i = 0; i<sheets.length; i++){}
```

To avoid mistake like this, please consider using

```
var i = 0
for(i in sheets){}
```

where i is automatically increment. Here some more details about [for/in statement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp)

Comment: Dude,again you solved my problems, you rock! I'll start using this for this way from now on.... Was going crazy on that hahaha. Thanks!